# How to read ToggleSwitch value in WinJS

Tags: winjs, toggleswitch

I want to read if one value is selected or another (1 or 0, TRUE or FALSE) in WinJS by using a ToggleSwitch:

Code HTML:

```
<div id="toggleSwitchDocFormat"  class="toggleSwitchDocFormat" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ToggleSwitch" data-win-options="{labelOn:'Guardar Documento Como: TIFF', labelOff:'Guardar Documento Como: PDF', checked:true}"></div>
```

Code Javascript:

```
app.onloaded = function () {
        getDomElements();

        toggleSwitchDocFormat = document.getElementById("toggleSwitchDocFormat").winControl;
        console.log("the value of the ToggleSwitch: " + toggleSwitchDocFormat.checked);

    }
```

Message:

> El código de biblioteca de JavaScript está a punto de detectar la
>   excepción. en línea 119, columna 9 en
>   ms-appx://.../js/default.js
>
> 0x800a138f - Error en tiempo de ejecución de JavaScript: No se puede
>   obtener la propiedad 'toString' de referencia nula o sin definir
>
> Si hay un controlador para esta excepción, el programa puede continuar
>   de forma segura.

when I hover the ToggleSwitch code I found "undefined" value, what am I doing wrong??

without the console.log line the ToggleSwitch is shown properly on screen, but I also want to get it's value, any help I'll appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code:

```
args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function () {

                document.getElementById("toggleSwitchDocFormat").winControl.addEventListener("change", function switchChanged(e) {
                    var _toggleSwitchDocFormat = e.target.winControl;
                    console.log("is it active??: " + _toggleSwitchDocFormat.checked);
                });
            }));
```

Comment: I took the reference from here http://bubblogging.wordpress.com/2013/02/17/winjs-controls-toggleswitch/